# Late applying css on page

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

The problem happen after moving ASP.NET from VS2010 to VS2017.

The problem is, while loading the page on browser, it flickers showing the content same as if css is not applied, and immediately apply it.

Screen shot while loading the page:
[image: Screen shot while loading the page]

Screen shot after loading the page:
[image: Screen shot after loading the page]

Comment: This is probably not caused by you version of Visual Studio, it sounds like a FOUC (Flash Of Unstyled Content), which can be caused by a number of things. Try researching FOUC and see if any solutions help you

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution for my problem, the solution was to add the links of the css files before the links of the java scripts files in the head section of the page.

Comment: Thank you. I had moved my site.css further down the page to make sure I was overriding any other css. However, I soon noticed the problem you had and was going crazy trying to fix it. (For at least 5 mins anyway before the magic of SO and finding your post).